# Windows 10 Universal App Getting data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, sqlite, crud, win-universal-app

I'm about to start Windows 10 Universal app development.

For my project I need to get data from a Microsoft SQL Server.

I know locally It is only possible to use SQLite but is there anyway I can interact with an SQL Server?

Comment: Create a web service. You don't want to access MSSQL over the internet. Try searching.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3767311/Creating-Native-Web-Services-in-SQL-Server.htm

Comment: No, that's an article from 2008. Look into WebAPI or WCF.

Comment: I see, I think this may be closer then? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f7f007/wcf-service-to-insert-and-retrieve-data-from-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Yeah that looks more like it, it's still a horrible tutorial. Check MSDN.com and ASP.net.

Comment: Thank you.  If you make an answer, I'll post it as accepted

Comment: Actually, Would you know if I have to host the service on IIS or can I reference it locally like in that tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t connect to a MS SQL Server directly from a Universal Windows App. As CodeCaster mentioned, the recommend way is creating a web service, and the app can retrieve the data through the web service.

For example:

**App -> data service on IIS (e.g. OData service) -> database (MS SQL Server)**

[How to: Deploying OData Services using IIS & SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192995.aspx)

You use the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639) to retrieve the data from OData service.

Comment: This is exactly how I have set up the project now. I have the UWA connecting though to a WCF application hosted on IIS which does all the SQL transactions. Thank you for your answer